# How to export queryset in Django 1.7 to xls file?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I using Django 1.7.1 with Python 3.4. I would like to export search results to Excel file. 
I have this function in view.py

```
def car_list(request):
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    search = request.GET.get('search') 

    if search is None:
        cars= Car.objects.filter(plate__isnull = False ).order_by('-created_date')
    else:
        cars= Car.objects.filter(plate__contains = search ).order_by('-created_date') 

    paginator = Paginator(cars, 100) # Show 100 contacts per page
    try:
        cars= paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        #if page is not an integer, deliver first page
        cars= paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        #if page is out of the range, deliver last page
        cars= paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    if request.REQUEST.get('excel'):
        # excel button clicked
        return download_workbook(request, cars)

return render_to_response('app/list.html', {'cars': cars}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

from .utils import queryset_to_workbook

def download_workbook(request, cars):
    queryset = cars
    columns = (
        'plante_number',
        'make',
        'model',
        'year')
    workbook = queryset_to_workbook(queryset, columns)
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="export.xls"'
    workbook.save(response)
    return response
```

and to be honest I don't know what to do in template to export it.
i have this button in my template `<input type="submit" name="excel" value="Export to Excel" />`
and when I use it i get:

```
TypeError at /

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/?search=&excel=Export+to+Excel
Django Version:     1.7.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'

Exception Location:     C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py in __init__, line 318
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version:     3.4.2
```

How can I fix this error? 
Please, give me some advice.
Thanks

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I googled it and it should be     `response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')`

Comment: You can answer you own question with this and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `mimetype` to `HttpResponse` is deprecated and removed in Django 1.7

You have to use `content_type`