# Serve a XLSX file django

Tags: python, django, excel

I am creating a xlsx file in memory using openpyxl and i need to serve it to the user. This is what i'm using now in my views.py and it's working but it's serving me a xls file and that's not completely correct, i need it to be XLSX and i would also like to be able to set the name of the downloaded file.

```
return HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(export_file), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

I did check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140806/django-serve-xlsx-file-and-force-download) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732812/how-to-export-queryset-in-django-1-7-to-xls-file) question but they don't help me too much.

Answer (score 1):

Did find it... it was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files).

Should change the application to

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```